# Leave a space between the corner of the phone and the progress bar in a swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I want the space progress bar between the edge of the phone to be 24. I want the size of the space to be 24. I also want the text to be aligned with the end of the bar. [image: Like this]

my code is like this:

```
struct SeasonsDetailsProgressBar: View {
    var bar : Float = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            HStack(spacing: 22){
                Text("Step")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Total steps taken")
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("3.214.629 / 5.000.0000")
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                        
                    }
                    ZStack(alignment:.leading){
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous)
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: 4)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous)
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width * CGFloat(bar),  height: 4)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0.965, green: 0.224, blue: 0.49))
                       
                    }.padding(.trailing ,
                              proxy.size.width * 0.9)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 25)
            .padding(.trailing, 25)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The output of the code is like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proxy.size.width gives us a width of screen you have to minus size of label and spacing between them.

```
struct SeasonsDetailsProgressBar: View {
    var bar : Float = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            HStack(spacing: 0) { // -> No spacing
                Text("Step")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .frame(width: 50, alignment: .leading) //  exact width of "Step" label
                    .padding(.leading, 24). // exactly 24 from the right side
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Total steps taken")
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("3.214.629 / 5.000.0000")
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                            .padding(.trailing, 24) // exactly 24 from left side
                        
                    }
                    ZStack(alignment:.leading){
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous)
                            .frame(width: (proxy.size.width - 98), height: 4) //  width of screen -(24 left + 50 label + 24 right)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous) // width-98
                            .frame(width: (proxy.size.width - 98) * CGFloat(bar),  height: 4)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0.965, green: 0.224, blue: 0.49))
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        } // no paddings
    }
}
```